# Use Python Pandas to read SAS transport file to get variable labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sas

I am using Pandas to import SAS transport files:

import pandas as pd

df = read_sas('AE.xpt', encoding = 'UTF-8')

This works fine to get the data into a data frame. The column headers are the names of the column/variable. Which is fine for most purposes, but I also want to use similar code to grab the variable labels. I don't see an option for this. I have seen some previous posts similar to this, but the answers seemed to focus on using tools other than Pandas. I prefer to stick with Pandas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The variables/columns in SAS transport files have labels associated with them. I want to know how to extract those labels with Pandas.